# Hide negative part of line chart in d3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have a d3.js line chart which may have negative values. My Y-span starts at 0 and goes up to the maximum value in the dataset. Thus, the line goes underneath the X-axis when there is a negative value.

This is fine, but what I need is to just hide the part of the line that is underneath the X-axis. I want to keep the values as they are, just use some CSS or JS to make the part of the line underneath the X-axis invisible.

I have tried with various overflow settings, but it doesn't seem to help. It is possible to make everything below the X-axis invisible by placing an element over that part, but then the X-axis labels are hidden too.

This is the code drawing the line:

```
x.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.date}), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.date})]);
y.domain([0, 1.05 * d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })]);
area.y0(y(0));

g.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("fill", "#f6f6f6")
    .attr("d", area);

//create line
var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function (d) { return y(d.value); });

g.append("path")
    .data([data])
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', '#068d46')
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c1bvrd50/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to clip the line inside a rectangle covering the positive values area. In SVG, this is done with [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath).

This happens in two steps:

1. Define a `rect` inside `clipPath`, covering the chart area only:

```
g.append('clipPath')
  .attr('id', 'clipRect')
  .append('rect')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
```

2. Clip the line path, using `clip-path` attribute:

```
g.append("path")
  .data([data])
  /* ... */
  .attr("d", valueline)
  .attr('clip-path', 'url("#clipRect")')
```

Updated jsFiddle implementing the solution: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fvdhsq5y/).

What is left to do is update the tooltip's `mousemove` event listener in order not to display the tooltip whenever the value is lower than 0.

Recommendation as P.S.: Whatever the use case of the chart is, it is most likely desirable to show the portions of the chart with negative values. Therefore, the chart's `y` axis should cover values lower than 0, rather than omitting these.